# native-app-builder ANT task does not update worklight.plist file (MFP v7.0)

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

Product: MobileFirst Platform v7.0

We are using the native-app-builder ANT task to build an MFP native iOS app. Though this task has the 'worklightserverhost' attribute, after running it, the worklight.plist file is not updated. We are expecting the host, protocol, port, and wlServerContext fields in the plist file to be updated after executing this ANT task.

As a side point, the app-builder ANT task (for hybrid apps) also has the 'worklightserverhost'  attribute. Executing this task does work as expected (i.e. the worklight.plist file is updated).

Is this a known problem? Is there a fix?

**Note**: By the worklight.plist file, we mean the file in the following folder: [MFP project folder]/apps/[MFP iOS native app folder]/worklight.plist

Answer (score 0):

A PMR (support ticket) was opened to investigate and address the issue raised in the question.

The only local workarounds are to either manually enter the server address details and copy the file to the required location, or to not use Ant as the tool to manipulate the file.